# define function as dictionary value to check conditions

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, for-loop

I want to create a dictionary that has keys and values, values has to be 3 elements long list. the first is a string that asks for input, the second a function that check a condition and the third a string to print if the condition is false

```py
dict = {
    'input 1': ['number > 10', def check(n): pass if n > 10 else raise ValueError, 'the number must be gratere than 10'],
    'input 2': ['3 words', def check(text): pass if len(text) == 3 else raise ValueError, 'must be 3 words'],
    'input 3': ['name', def check(text, name_list): pass if text in name_list else raise ValueError, 'the name has to be one of them '.format(x = name_list)]
}

for i in dict:
    while True:
        text = input(dict[i][0])
        try:
            dict[i][1](text)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print(dict[i][2])
```

I know this is very strange but the dict is very long and with very different conditions.
I don't even know how can I pass multiple arguments to the funcs that need more than one

Comment: I see you have posted some code. How is it working for you?

Comment: The `name` check requires 2 arguments, you're only passing 1. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: There are multiple issues here. First off, yes it is possible to store functions in a list, but the syntax you show does not work. As for passing multiple arguments - *where will they come from*? If the functions will have a *different number* of arguments, *how do you want to decide* the number of arguments, after you have looked up the function? We can't design your requirements for you.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you ask.  Take some time to note the changes I've made here.
Note that the functions must all accept the same parameters.

```
def check_num( val ):
    n = int(val )
    if n <= 10:
        raise ValueError( 'the number must be greater than 10' )

def check_3( val ):
    if len(val.split()) != 3:
        raise ValueError( 'must be 3 words' )

def check_name( val ):
    if text not in name_list:
        raise ValueError( 'the name must e one of' + (' '.join(name_list)) )

data = {
    'input 1': ['Enter number', check_num],
    'input 2': ['Enter 3 words', check_3],
    'input 3': ['Enter a name', check_name]
}

name_list = ['Bill', 'Ted', 'Tom']

for i,info in data.items():
    while True:
        text = input(info[0]+': ')
        try:
            info[1](text)
            break
        except ValueError as e:
            print( e )
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your functions take only the input text as argument, make your function return a bool value:

```
dict = {
    'input 1': ['number > 10', lambda n: n > 10, 'the number must be gratere than 10'],
    'input 2': ['3 words', lambda text:len(text) == 3, 'must be 3 words'],
    'input 3': ['name', lambda text: text in name_list, 'the name has to be one of them '.format(x = name_list)]
}

for i in dict:
    while True:
        text = input(dict[i][0])
        res = dict[i][1](text)
        if res:
            break
        else:
            print(dict[i][2])
```

There is no easy way to make your third function work, because it requires a different number of arguments, I suggest setting name_list as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lambda` to create function expressions in the list, not `def`. But lambda can only contain a single expression to evaluate and return; `pass` and `raise` are statements, not expressions.

So you'll need to define these functions outside the dictionary, then reference them there.

And since you never use the dictionary keys, iterate over the `values()`.

Don't use `dict` as a variable name, it overwrites the built-in class with that name.

`name_list` will need to be a global variable. All the check functions can only take 1 argument, since the loop has no way of knowing that some functions require additional arguments. It just passes the input text.

```
def check_greater_10(n):
    if n <= 10:
        raise ValueError

def check_3_words(text):
    if len(text.split()) != 3:
        raise ValueError

def check_name_list(text):
    if text not in name_list:
        raise ValueError

mydict = {
    'input 1': ['number > 10', check_greater_10, 'the number must be greater than 10'],
    'input 2': ['3 words', check_3_words, 'must be 3 words'],
    'input 3': ['name', check_name_list, 'the name has to be one of them: {x} '.format(x = name_list)]
}

for prompt, check, error in mydict.values():
    while True:
        text = input(prompt)
        try:
            prompt(text)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print(error)
```

Answer (score -4):

get input using `readlines()` function:

```
import sys
inputx = sys.stdin.readline()
print(inputx)
```

for no of lines use `sys.stdin.readlines()` but it must be given under for loop with range

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: to get multiple inputs and to apply them to the function.

Comment: `input()` does the same thing.

Comment: The question isn't about getting input, it already does that correctly with `input(dict[i][0])`. The question is about calling the check functions.

Comment: sry. I thought of getting no. of line inputs.